# Connecting well to home using water hose

Tags: water, pump, well-pump

I had a new well pump installed they used 1 inch tubing and connected it to my 3/4 water lines....it has popped all my joints and flooded my back yard.  Had to shut power off to the pump and stop all water. How can I lay a new water line above ground connecting my well pump to my house?

Comment: what are `all my joints` ? ..... `How can I lay a new water line above ground connecting my well pump to my house?` ... buy enough pipe to reach from the well to your house and connect pipes end to end .................. please ask the question that you want to ask, instead of the silly question that you actually asked

Comment: The 1 inch line had nothing to do with popping joints. There is supposed to be a pressure regulator/damper in the system.

Comment: @jsotola please be more courteous in your comments to others.  Calling questions silly is insulting.  People asking these questions often don't know why the idea inherent in the question is bad, they don't have our background, and being mean to them isn't helpful.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick temporary fix until everything can be repaired make sure to use a potable water hose, RV stores have these hoses and a regulator that can be adjusted to prevent the high pressure that caused your plumbing to fail. Adjusting the pressure switch to a lower setting should be done at a minimum, but use the food grade hose or potable water hose because standard garden hoses can leach nasties into the water.

Answer (score 3):

As Jim Stewart said in the comments, this likely has nothing to do with the pipe size.   Reducing water line size is a common practice.  The pressure is the problem - the pump is generating more than the system can handle and causing damage.

You asked "how can I lay a new water line" and specified above ground.  Usually this is a bad idea because above ground water lines are subject to conditions harmful to them like cold weather (freezing lines will eventually rupture), and general exposure to the elements and things like lawn mowers, trimmers, etc.

You should plan to bury the water line the same way the old one was - although in your case you probably should be contacting the installer (and possibly a lawyer) to repair the damage and pay for the water damage in the house.